# How do I fix this issue with my number finder?

Tags: python

I’m trying to make a number finder to prove a point to a friend that you can get to any number from 1 - 100 with only 7 numbers but i cant make it work the way i want it to. The output is just a continuous list of 62’s and I can’t see the problem. Can anybody help? 
Here's my code -

```
numbers = list(range(0,101))
numbers_to_add_take_away = [25,13,6,3,1,1,1]
target = 62

found_number = False

def halfing_sequence():
    x = 0
    mid = 50
    half = int(numbers[mid])
    if mid == target:
        print('Match!')
        found_number = True
        quit()
    elif target > half:
        mid = int(mid + (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    elif target < half:
        mid = int(mid - (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    x = x + 1
    print(mid)


while found_number == False:
    halfing_sequence()
```

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Can you please edit your question with a title that is related to your issue for SEO purposes?

Comment: You should edit your title so it is related to your problem, show us the output you get with your algorithm, and the desired output. And what is the purpose of `numbers_to_add_take_away` ?

Comment: Could you explain what the code is meant to do? Few mistakes off the bat. halfing_sequence() never returns anything. found_number in the main thread is never True. You never go more than one step into halfing_sequence since x and mid are always set to the same values in your function call.

Comment: @SterlingArcher thank you for notifying me and I have made the changes as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `x` and `mid` outside your function `halfing_sequence`, and then you can use them with the keyword `global` :

```
numbers = list(range(0,101))
numbers_to_add_take_away = [25,13,6,3,1,1]
target = 62

found_number = False
x = 0
mid = 50

def halfing_sequence():
    global x, mid
    half = int(numbers[mid])
    if mid == target:
        print('Match!')
        found_number = True
        quit()
    elif target > half:
        mid = int(mid + (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    elif target < half:
        mid = int(mid - (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    x = x + 1
    print(mid)

while found_number == False:
    halfing_sequence()
```

Output :

```
75
62
Match!
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` never changes and neither does `mid` as each time you call the function they reset to 0 and 50. One solution would be to make x and mid arguments of the function and the use recursion to call the function again until a solution is found

```
numbers = list(range(0,101))
numbers_to_add_take_away = [25,13,6,3,1,1]
target = 62

found_number = False

def halfing_sequence(x, mid):
    half = int(numbers[mid])
    if mid == target:
        print('Match!')
        quit()
    elif target > half:
        mid = int(mid + (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    elif target < half:
        mid = int(mid - (numbers_to_add_take_away[x]))
    x = x + 1
    print(x)
    print(mid)
    halfing_sequence(x, mid)


x=0
mid=50
halfing_sequence(x=0, mid=50)
```